# Moongose find with or without a condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have a simple issue with a node.js/mongodb application. I want to get all users if the user is a Super Admin and if the user is a Normal Admin I need only users of the same client.

I have tried something like this:

```
const client = req.user.role === 'SA_ROLE'? null : req.user.client;
User.find({'client': client})...
```

and also:

```
const client = req.user.role === 'SA_ROLE'? '': req.user.client;
User.find({'client': client})...
```

But in both cases when the user is SA, it returns cero users.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all user, the filter should be `{}`. So this code may work:

```
let query = req.user.role === 'SA_ROLE'? {} : {client: req.user.client};
User.find(query)...
```